# Storing a D3 selection and then calling enter() fails to render

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement the general update pattern in D3, to allow me to update existing elements before entering new ones.

This code works and generates the elements I want:

```
var nodes = nodeGroup.selectAll(".node")
     .data(root.descendants())
     .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y +")"; 
        })
```

Now I want to change the code to store the update selection and modify some attributes before retrieving the enter selection.

But when I make this simple change, nothing gets appended any more:

```
var nodes = nodeGroup.selectAll(".node")
     .data(root.descendants())

nodes.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y +")"; 
        })
```

Why don't these two pieces of code behave identically?

Comment: The two snippets themselves behave exactly the same. It's the code executed afterwards, that is affected. In the first snippet `nodes` holds a reference to the enter selection whereas in the second snippet `nodes` refers to the update selection instead. Use `nodes = nodes.enter().append("g")` in the second case to have `nodes` point to the enter selection like in the first one.

Comment: Of course! Thank you.